# Skipping errors in a loop when webscraping

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, error-handling

I have taken links from one page (159 totalled) and now want to run them through a loop and get information on each of their pages.
When I do this I am getting an error as one of the links is coming back with an error (I think that is why it is erroring out)
Any advise/direction or help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

See code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

baseurl = "https://www.auveco.com"

productlinks = []

r = requests.get('https://www.auveco.com/products')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
productlist = soup.find_all('li', class_='opened')


for item in productlist:
    for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
        productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])
#print(productlinks)

#part#2

partno = []
for link in productlinks:

    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    try:
        name = soup.find_all('li', class_='product-code').text
    except:
        name='nopage'
    print(name)
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 382, in prepare_url
    scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\url.py", line 392, in parse_url
    return six.raise_from(LocationParseError(source_url), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: https://www.auveco.comjavascript:void(0);

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ppluc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\auv22.py", line 30, in <module>
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 316, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 384, in prepare_url
    raise InvalidURL(*e.args)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: https://www.auveco.comjavascript:void(0);
nopage
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap `r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)` in a try - except block, like:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Then we can also skip the other parsing steps, if the get fails:

```
#part#2

partno = []
for link in productlinks:
    try:
        r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        
        name = soup.find_all('li', class_='product-code').text
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL as e:
        print(str(e))
        name='url invalid'
    except:
        name='nopage'
    print(name)
```